# Split a vector into vector of vectors in clojure instead of vector of lists

Tags: clojure

The clojure documentation of [split-at](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/split-at) states that it takes a collection of elements  and returns a [vector](http://clojure.org/data_structures#vectors) of two [lists](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Lists), each containing elements greater or smaller than a given index:

```
(split-at 2 [1 2 3 4 5])
[(1 2) (3 4 5)]
```

What I want is this:

```
(split-at' 2 [1 2 3 4 5])
[[1 2] [3 4 5]]
```

This is a collection cut into two collections that keep the order of the elements (like vectors), preferably without performance penalties.

What is the usual way to do this and are there any performance optimized ways to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're working exclusively with vectors, one option would be to use `subvec`.

```
(defn split-at' [idx v]
    [(subvec v 0 idx) (subvec v idx)])

(split-at' 2 [1 2 3 4 5])
;; => [[1 2] [3 4 5]]
```

As regards to performance, the docs on `subvec` state:

> This operation is O(1) and very fast, as
>   the resulting vector shares structure with the original and no
>   trimming is done.

Comment: Needs fixing for the empty vector. Which works find with `split-at`

Comment: @ClojureMostly It seems to work fine for the empty vector, as far as I can tell: `(= [[] []] (split-at' 0 []))`

Comment: @ClojureMostly Ah, that makes sense; I would argue that that's not technically valid usage of the function, but I suppose there could be situations where that behavior is useful.

Comment: I agree! Better to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Why not extend the core function with "vec" function ?

So based on split-at definition:

```
(defn split-at
  "Returns a vector of [(take n coll) (drop n coll)]"
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [n coll]
    [(take n coll) (drop n coll)])
```

We can add vec to each element of the vector result

```
(defn split-at-vec
  [n coll]
    [(vec (take n coll)) (vec (drop n coll))])
```

Releated to "performance penalties" i think that when you transform your lazy seqs in favor of vector then you loose the lazy performance.