# Clojure: how to move vector elements in a map elegantly

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In clojure, I am trying to accomplish the following logic:

```
Input:
{:a [11 22 33] :b [10 20 30]}, 2
Output:
{:a [11] :b [10 20 30 22 33]}
```

i.e. Move the last 2 elements from :a to :b

Is there a clojurish way for this operation?

Comment: what does the "2" specify? The transformation you give as an example could have several interpretations, so it might be best to describe with an additional example, or use a few words. For example, is it the last 2 elements from `:a` you want to move to `:b`, or all but the first?  And, will there only be `:a` and `:b`, or only those two?

Comment: @Josh Sorry for the confusion. Updated in the question what "2" means.

Comment: Just a tip for the future: in your question, you should post your best attempt to solve the problem, and then ask for additional help assuming you're not satisfied with your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're effectively modifying both mappings in the map, it's probably easiest to explicitly deconstruct the map and just return the new map via a literal, using [`subvec`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subvec) and [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) for the vector manipulation:

```
(defn move [m n]
  (let [{:keys [a b]} m
        i (- (count a) n)
        left (subvec a 0 i)
        right (subvec a i)]
    {:a left :b (into b right)}))

(move {:a [11 22 33] :b [10 20 30]} 2)
;;=> {:a [11], :b [10 20 30 22 33]}
```

As a bonus, this particular implementation is both very idiomatic and very fast.

Alternatively, using the `split-at'` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21377579/5044950), you could write it like this:

```
(defn split-at' [n v]
  [(subvec v 0 n) (subvec v n)])

(defn move [m n]
  (let [{:keys [a b]} m
        [left right] (split-at' (- (count a) n) a)]
    {:a left :b (into b right)}))
```

Comment: Nice answer to split-at then move the second part onto the end of the first. Makes think there's a Clojure function to do it: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/split-at

Comment: @ChrisMurphy That would be slower than `subvec`, which is constant time. It may be worth defining a [`split-at'`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21377579/5044950) function for vectors here, though.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy I added an alternative implementation using that `split-at'` function.

Comment: Suggest you call the function `split-atv`, not `split-at'`, by analogy with `map` => `mapv`.

Comment: @Thumbnail I can see that, yeah. The only problem I have with that is that I think it works better with `map` and `mapv` because `map` is only one word (no hyphen), so it looks a bit weirder with `split-atv` (someone may think "atv" is supposed to mean something).

Comment: @SamEstep True.

Answer (score 2):

First, using the sub-vec in the other answers will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException when the number of elements to be moved is greater than the size of the collection.

Secondly, the destructuring, the way most have done here, couples the function to one specific data structure. This being, a map with keys :a and :b and values for these keys that are vectors. Now if you change one of the keys in the input, then you need to also change it in move function.

My solution follows:

```
(defn move [colla collb n]
  (let [newb (into (into [] collb) (take-last n colla))
        newa (into [] (drop-last n colla))]
       [newa newb]))
```

This should work for any collection and will return vector of 2 vectors. My solution is far more reusable. Try:

`(move (range 100000) (range 200000) 10000)`

#### Edit:

Now you can use first and second to access the vector you need in the return.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it just a little differently than Josh:

```
(defn tx-vals [ {:keys [a b]} num-to-move ]
  {:a (drop-last num-to-move a)
   :b (concat b (take-last num-to-move a)) } )

(tx-vals {:a [11 22 33], :b [10 20 30]} 2) 
      => {:a (11),       :b (10 20 30 22 33)}
```

## Update

Sometimes it may be more convenient to use the `clojure.core/split-at` function as follows:

```
(defn tx-vals-2 [ {:keys [a b]} num-to-move ]
  (let [ num-to-keep        (- (count a) num-to-move)
        [a-head, a-tail]   (split-at num-to-keep a) ]
    { :a a-head
     :b (concat b a-tail) } ))
```

If vectors are preferred on output (my favorite!), just do:

```
(defn tx-vals-3 [ {:keys [a b]} num-to-move ]
  (let [ num-to-keep        (- (count a) num-to-move)
         [a-head, a-tail]   (split-at num-to-keep a) ]
    {:a (vec a-head)
     :b (vec (concat b a-tail))} ))
```

to get the results:

```
(tx-vals-2 data 2) => {:a (11), :b (10 20 30 22 33)}
(tx-vals-3 data 2) => {:a [11], :b [10 20 30 22 33]}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it has asymptotic complexity O(`(count a)`), whereas mine has O(`num-to-move`), which is an actual (asymptotic), rather than just a constant factor, difference. And you can't point to laziness as providing constant time here, because the OP specifically asked for vectors, and to get back vectors in the result map you would need to force the sequences.

Comment: In response to the update: as I said before, forcing the sequences (by calling `vec`) just gives you the worst of both worlds: you don't get the laziness of the approach used here, and you don't get the asymptotic performance of the approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn f [{:keys [a b]} n]
  (let [last-n (take-last n a)]
    {:a (into [] (take (- (count a) n) a))
     :b (into b last-n)}))

(f {:a [11 22 33] :b [10 20 30]} 2)
=> {:a [11], :b [10 20 30 22 33]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if the order of those items does not matter, here is my attempt:

```
(def m {:a [11 22 33] :b [10 20 30]})

(defn so-42476918 [{:keys [a b]} n]
  (zipmap [:a :b] (map vec (split-at (- (count a) n) (concat a b)))))

(so-42476918 m 2)
```

gives:

```
{:a [11], :b [22 33 10 20 30]}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would go with an approach, which differs a bit from the previous answers (well, technically it is the same, but it differs on the application-scale level).

First of all, transferring data between two collections is quite a frequent task, so it at least deserves some special utility function for that in your library:

```
(defn transfer [from to n & {:keys [get-from put-to]
                             :or {:get-from :start :put-to :end}}]
  (let [f (if (= get-from :end)
            (partial split-at (- (count from) n))
            (comp reverse (partial split-at n)))
        [from swap] (f from)]
    [from (if (= put-to :start)
            (concat swap to)
            (concat to swap))]))
```

ok, it looks verbose, but it lets you transfer data from start/end of one collection to start/end of the other:

```
user> (transfer [1 2 3] [4 5 6] 2)
[(3) (4 5 6 1 2)]

user> (transfer [1 2 3] [4 5 6] 2 :get-from :end)
[(1) (4 5 6 2 3)]

user> (transfer [1 2 3] [4 5 6] 2 :put-to :start)
[(3) (1 2 4 5 6)]

user> (transfer [1 2 3] [4 5 6] 2 :get-from :end :put-to :start)
[(1) (2 3 4 5 6)]
```

So what's left, is to make your domain specific function on top of it:

```
(defn move [data n]
  (let [[from to] (transfer (:a data) (:b data) n
                            :get-from :end
                            :put-to :end)]
    (assoc data
           :a (vec from)
           :b (vec to))))

user> (move {:a [1 2 3 4 5] :b [10 20 30 40] :c [:x :y]} 3)
{:a [1 2], :b [10 20 30 40 3 4 5], :c [:x :y]}
```